# How to display a data label on a region consisting of multiple countries which are sperated from each other in highmaps?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, label, data-visualization, highmaps

I have following scenario:
I have created a region consisting of UK and Cyprus in highmaps.
When I display the data label, the label appears in the middle between the countries.
[MY custom region with label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeZQo.png)

But in my application there are other countries in the map. So the label "My region" will be displayed on Switzerland or some other country whicht is between UK and Cyprus.

How can avoid this behavior? Or how can I display my label on the relevant area?

'$(function () {

```
var path = "M971,-54L971,-54L971,-54L971,-55ZM977,-58L979,-56L975,-54L972,-56L974,-57L975,-57ZM970,-53L970,-48L958,-39L954,-39L952,-37L944,-37L938,-46L942,-46L944,-50L945,-50L945,-51L946,-51L950,-49L957,-54L962,-56L965,-52L970,-53L970,-53ZM972,-54L972,-54L972,-54L972,-54ZM108,-534L107,-530L106,-533L103,-534ZM166,-521L168,-518L164,-519L165,-515L164,-509L165,-507L164,-502L163,-490L158,-483L157,-479L153,-475L152,-470L145,-474L143,-472L134,-473L131,-470L127,-470L123,-468L119,-468L110,-464L108,-465L100,-465L98,-466L91,-466L96,-469L98,-472L88,-471L88,-473L95,-475L89,-475L84,-480L87,-482L94,-482L94,-484L85,-486L86,-488L91,-489L96,-486L97,-490L96,-492L101,-492L102,-494L108,-493L113,-493L114,-496L110,-493L104,-496L99,-496L106,-498L109,-503L107,-503L112,-508L117,-506L118,-510L107,-512L108,-515L104,-515L106,-517L102,-517L101,-523L106,-523L107,-527L112,-526L113,-529L107,-529L109,-531L108,-539L112,-541L121,-537L121,-534L124,-537L133,-534L130,-537L137,-540L141,-543L132,-544L131,-547L135,-549L139,-549L137,-552L142,-557L149,-556L152,-557L153,-551L154,-557L157,-557L157,-560L162,-553L157,-551L154,-549L150,-543L145,-544L146,-540L138,-538L142,-530L149,-525L156,-532L158,-530L158,-526L160,-524L160,-521ZM209,-378L210,-375L206,-376L207,-378ZM230,-416L234,-413L229,-411L226,-414ZM187,-495L187,-495L188,-493L186,-494ZM194,-493L196,-492L191,-489L188,-493L188,-496L193,-496ZM191,-553L188,-555L189,-560L192,-560ZM195,-560L193,-562L193,-566L195,-565ZM179,-567L179,-562L176,-563L175,-566L172,-564L174,-568L179,-570ZM180,-574L179,-573L178,-573L179,-575ZM186,-574L186,-572L181,-566L180,-569ZM171,-586L170,-588L174,-588L171,-587ZM185,-588L185,-585L188,-583L189,-580L178,-579L182,-584L180,-587L184,-589ZM177,-589L175,-589L177,-590L179,-591ZM167,-602L166,-601L165,-602L166,-604ZM184,-599L183,-597L181,-599L183,-600ZM170,-613L172,-610L168,-605L168,-609ZM172,-615L173,-613L171,-613L170,-614ZM174,-619L174,-615L169,-619L170,-620ZM242,-638L241,-635L240,-638L241,-638ZM237,-640L238,-638L236,-638L235,-640ZM240,-647L245,-640L243,-639L241,-642L238,-641L236,-644L237,-647ZM247,-646L249,-644L247,-644L247,-646ZM242,-648L242,-646L241,-647L241,-648ZM246,-649L246,-646L245,-646L245,-648ZM251,-649L249,-648L248,-648L249,-649ZM244,-652L244,-649L243,-650L242,-652ZM279,-681L279,-680L278,-680L277,-682ZM273,-670L269,-663L268,-664L271,-673L268,-670L266,-675L270,-675L270,-680L267,-680L272,-683L270,-677L274,-678ZM276,-685L277,-685L275,-679L274,-679ZM280,-686L279,-684L277,-684L279,-688ZM202,-384L200,-384L200,-385L203,-386ZM192,-515L189,-515L191,-519L194,-522L197,-523L197,-520ZM75,-33L75,-32L75,-33ZM958,-39L956,-38L952,-37L954,-39ZM975,-54L974,-53L972,-54L972,-54L972,-54L972,-54L970,-53L970,-53L970,-53L970,-54L969,-55L969,-55L971,-55L974,-57L974,-57L974,-57L972,-56ZM971,-54L971,-55L971,-54L971,-54ZM269,-427L271,-426L279,-426L277,-419L271,-418L269,-414L266,-415L259,-413L257,-412L249,-415L242,-415L238,-414L237,-417L230,-417L219,-416L217,-413L210,-416L209,-414L203,-420L196,-419L191,-417L191,-413L187,-408L184,-409L179,-414L168,-415L167,-413L163,-413L162,-409L159,-407L155,-412L151,-411L152,-414L156,-414L164,-419L165,-421L169,-422L175,-427L176,-433L179,-432L183,-437L190,-436L196,-433L202,-432L203,-436L209,-440L214,-446L210,-442L205,-442L201,-438L195,-440L191,-447L188,-445L183,-446L182,-452L177,-452L172,-450L172,-453L168,-459L172,-461L177,-461L188,-465L192,-472L193,-482L188,-482L186,-480L182,-481L186,-484L190,-486L194,-491L208,-491L211,-488L211,-492L213,-493L213,-496L217,-500L215,-502L216,-506L220,-511L217,-514L213,-512L211,-520L209,-523L215,-533L218,-534L213,-536L212,-533L208,-534L205,-531L202,-533L199,-536L199,-530L192,-537L190,-536L191,-531L188,-537L191,-545L199,-553L196,-560L197,-564L199,-566L199,-570L196,-564L193,-566L191,-566L190,-563L187,-560L185,-553L181,-552L186,-563L186,-569L190,-574L188,-576L191,-580L196,-581L192,-582L196,-588L189,-583L185,-587L187,-589L182,-590L183,-592L188,-590L189,-594L195,-604L192,-606L193,-613L196,-611L195,-616L195,-620L199,-621L200,-619L202,-621L206,-618L202,-625L204,-624L204,-629L208,-629L207,-631L211,-638L216,-635L228,-633L234,-634L239,-633L237,-630L237,-627L235,-624L221,-617L221,-614L224,-613L216,-606L226,-608L228,-609L234,-607L236,-607L242,-605L250,-604L252,-598L248,-595L246,-589L242,-583L238,-580L236,-576L230,-574L231,-571L234,-568L231,-566L228,-567L224,-564L218,-564L225,-561L230,-563L232,-562L239,-557L243,-549L245,-547L245,-535L247,-524L249,-520L257,-514L259,-508L264,-503L261,-501L262,-498L265,-490L262,-490L259,-494L260,-490L265,-486L267,-478L266,-475L260,-470L266,-467L270,-471L276,-470L281,-468L287,-464L288,-455L285,-450L284,-445L276,-440L275,-438L273,-439L270,-432L263,-432L267,-430L264,-429L268,-427L268,-429L270,-428L270,-427ZM189,-607L189,-605L194,-604L193,-602L187,-598L188,-603L184,-603L182,-608L179,-613L182,-613L182,-616L185,-613L187,-618L189,-614L188,-609L189,-607L189,-610L191,-612L190,-609ZM180,-634L184,-633L184,-635L193,-639L193,-634L189,-631L189,-627L185,-624L178,-621L177,-623L181,-625L178,-628ZM157,-551L159,-549L162,-553L165,-552L170,-552L175,-550L178,-536L180,-533L181,-528L179,-525L179,-530L176,-526L178,-524L173,-523L169,-519L166,-521L160,-521L160,-524L158,-526L158,-530L156,-532L149,-525L142,-530L138,-538L146,-540L145,-544L150,-543L154,-549ZM977,-58L977,-58L977,-58L975,-57L974,-57L974,-57L975,-58ZM944,-50L944,-50L944,-50L945,-50L945,-51L945,-51L945,-51L945,-50ZM946,-51L946,-51L947,-51L950,-50L957,-55L962,-57L964,-55L969,-55L969,-55L970,-54L970,-53L965,-52L962,-56L957,-54L950,-49ZM964,-55L962,-57L957,-55L950,-50L947,-51L950,-52L949,-59L961,-61L973,-69L983,-79L983,-78L973,-63L977,-58L975,-58L974,-57L974,-57L971,-55L969,-55L969,-55ZM944,-50L945,-51L945,-51L945,-50ZM530,10L525,9L524,6L529,7ZM523,5L521,5L523,4L525,5Z";

// Initiate the chart
$('#container').highcharts('Map', {
    series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,

            format: 'My Region'         
        },
        data: [{
            path: path,
            'iso-a2': 'EUR',
            value: 20
        }]
    }]
});
```

});`

https://jsfiddle.net/4rcdgfmf/1/

Comment: That depends on what you want it to actually do. What placement of the label would be appropriate in your view?I don't know that it's reasonable to expect the library to understand where you might want it :) Frankly I don't know that it makes sense at all to try to label it in the way that you describe. This seems like something more appropriate for colors by region, and the legend. You can look at the overall `labels` object, however, and place a label wherever you want on the chart: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/labels

Comment: I want the label always be displayed on the region. Colors by region doesn't make sense in my application, because every region has to have the same color.

Comment: Right. But if your `region` is broken up as you describe, what is it that you want to happen? Saying that you want it to "always be displayed on the region" doesn't explain your desired outcome for the problem you've posted.

Comment: I mean that I want the label to be displayed on the blue area. As you see in screenshot there is UK and Cyprus. I want the label to be displayed on UK for example or on both countries.